# Exporting result of multiple select statement with db2 export command?

Tags: db2, export-to-csv, db2-luw

Is it possible to export result of multiple select statement with db2 "export" command ( https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html ) like db2 command line processor (ie db2 -tvf file.sql with many sql request in file.sql) ?

Best regards

Comment: Each export command can handle a single result-set.  Explain what your *real* requirement is?  You can run multiple export commands (one per result-set) , also from SQL via admin_proc stored procedure you can run run the stored-procedure to perform the export as many times as needed. Depending on your Db2-LUW you can also write to external tables (with Db2 v11.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
$ cat export
export to f1 of del values 1;
export to f2 of del values 2;

$ db2 -tf export
SQL3104N  The Export utility is beginning to export data to file "f1".

SQL3105N  The Export utility has finished exporting "1" rows.


Number of rows exported: 1


SQL3104N  The Export utility is beginning to export data to file "f2".

SQL3105N  The Export utility has finished exporting "1" rows.


Number of rows exported: 1
```

Comment: Thanks it's an interesting way of thinking !